# Google Now doesn't show all information about a tracking

Tags: email, gmail, google-schemas, google-now

I am sending emails to gmail with the tracking code of the orders that my customers make. The idea is that gmail recognizes the tracking and show the information in the email message and in Google Now application on an android device.

The code I use is this:

```
<html lang="es" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
</head>
<body link="#ff6000" alink="#ff6000" vlink="#ff6000">
    <table width="658px"  cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" style="margin: 0 auto; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: #333333;">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/email/cabecera.gif" alt="Logotipo" title="Logotipo" style="border: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px;" alt="Logotipo"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #e4dfd7; background-color: #f5f2ee; padding-top: 30px;">
                    <div style="background: url(http://www.example.com/images/email/fd-sup.gif) top center no-repeat; padding-top: 7px;">
                        <div style="background: url(http://www.example.com/images/email/fd-inf.gif) bottom center no-repeat; padding-bottom: 13px;">
                            <div style="background: #ffffff url(http://www.example.com/images/email/logotipo.gif) bottom left no-repeat; width: 481px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; min-height: 250px;">
                                <div style="padding: 25px 40px 15px 40px"><p><div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ParcelDelivery">
      <div itemprop="deliveryAddress" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="NAME"/>
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="ADDRESS"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="CITY"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="REGION"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="ES"/>
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="ZIP"/>
      </div>
      <div itemprop="originAddress" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="company"/>
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="street"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="City"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="region"/>
        <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="ES"/>
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="zip"/>
      </div>
      <meta itemprop="expectedArrivalFrom" content="2015-01-06T00:00:00-08:00"/>
      <meta itemprop="expectedArrivalUntil" content="2015-01-08T00:00:00-08:00"/>
      <div itemprop="carrier" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="company"/>
      </div>
        <div itemprop = "itemShipped" itemscope="" itemtype = "http://schema.org/Product">
        <meta itemprop = "name" content = "Engel RS 4800Y HD SAT WiFi" />
        <link itemprop = "url" href = "http://www.example.com/engel_rs_4800y_hd_sat_wifi.html" />
        <link itemprop = "image" href = "http://www.example.com/fotos/tv_satelite/engel_rs_4800_hd_sat_wifi.jpg" />
        <meta itemprop = "sku" content = "52314" />
      </div><meta itemprop="trackingNumber" content="0030180030181000367570001"/>
      <link itemprop="trackingUrl" href="https://www.example.com/#showOrders"/>
      <link itemprop="hasDeliveryMethod" href="http://schema.org/ParcelService"/>
      <div itemprop="partOfOrder" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
        <meta itemprop="orderNumber" content="order number"/>
        <div itemprop="merchant" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
          <meta itemprop="name" content="company"/>
          <link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://www.example.com"/>
        </div>
        <link itemprop="orderStatus" href="http://schema.org/OrderInTransit"/>
      </div>
    </div> <p>SOME TEXT HERE
            </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
                <table width="100%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" style="padding: 10px 0 5px 0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="bottom"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/email/tit-lideres.gif" style=" border:0px"></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;">

                        </td>
                    </tr>                       
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

The thing is that in Google Now a card appears but only with the text "Order sent. Origin: The name o f the company", but there's nothing about the tracking, order number, items and so on. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Google now for Track package, it displays a product title, product image and also the name of the website it is ordered from.

I see that the product image URL in the markup you added, is not a valid URL or there is no image in that URL.

```
<link itemprop = "image" href = "http://www.example.com/fotos/tv_satelite/engel_rs_4800_hd_sat_wifi.jpg" />
```

You can refer [here](https://www.google.com/landing/now/#cards/packages) for more details.

Hope that helps!